# Get different result from broadcasting when changing dimension

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm using 
`sum(self.eval_h(self.x) * self.w.reshape(1, self.n)) / sum(self.w)` to do a dot product and

where `eval_h` is defined as

```
def eval_h(self, x):
    """
    evaluate h
    """
    if "h_params" in self.kwargs:
        if x.ndim == 1:
            return self.h(x, **self.kwargs["h_params"])
        else:
            return apply_along_axis(lambda x: self.h(x, **self.kwargs["h_params"]), 1, x)
    else:
        if x.ndim == 1:
            return self.h(x)
        else:
            return apply_along_axis(lambda x: self.h(x), 1, x)
```

and `x` is of shape

```
def pop_x(self):
    """
    populate x with zeros
    """
    self.x = zeros((self.n, self.d))
```

The result turns out to be different when `x` has one dimension from `x` has more than one dimension.

In case `x` has more than one dimension, `self.w.reshape(1, self.n)` gives the correct result. In case `x` has only one dimension, `self.w.reshape(self.n, 1)` gives the correct result. Actually I don't think I really understand broadcasting so every time I'm seeing it I'm just using it by luck.

Comment: This is a very good explanation of broadcasting http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/EricsBroadcastingDoc

Comment: It would be easier to force `x` to have consistent dimensions at the start, than trying accommodate 1 vs 2d at several points.